# Get all objects within specific range in GeoFire

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, geofire

Is it possible to retrieve all keys within the specific range, using Firebase's GeoFire?
I am aware that you can receive events for geo queries, like: key entered, key exited or key moved, however I am currently looking for something more like FEventTypeValue (one time value read, for the specific geo region), because my map objects are not moving.

Can't find anything in the docs: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc

Comment: If your object aren't moving, then you'll get exactly one key entered event for each record. You can monitor `[query observeWithReadyBlock...` to know when all the events have loaded and then use [removeObserverWithHandle](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching) to stop listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the key entered events to first save all keys for a query in a dictionary and then use the ready event to determine when all keys have been added:

```
NSMutableDictionary *allKeys = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[query observeEventType:GFEventTypeKeyEntered withBlock:^(NSString *key, CLLocation *location) {
    [allKeys setObject:location forKey:key];
}];
[query observeReadyWithBlock:^{
    // Create an immutable copy of the keys in the query
    NSDictionary *valueData = [allKeys copy];
    NSLog(@"All keys within a query: %@", valueData);
}];
```

Don't forget to clean up your listeners afterwards.

Comment: That's the way to do it. For the future readers - please note, that you should choose some meaningful and unique id when creating a key in a method:
   [geofire setLocation:forKey:I_E_FIREBASE_UNIQUE_ID]
Store the geofire objects under single node within your tree like: "geofireSth" and create index on geofireSth's "g" node.
That way, you will be able to use the query from @johnnydee example to retrieve objects within specific radius. Use the key retrieved from the query (I_E_FIREBASE_UNIQUE_ID), to perform server request for additional data about the object.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't that exactly what you looking for?

GeoFire allows you to query **all** keys within a geographic area using GFQuery objects.

**Objective-C:**

```
  CLLocation *center = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.7832889 longitude:-122.4056973];
    // Query locations at [37.7832889, -122.4056973] with a radius of 600 meters
    GFCircleQuery *circleQuery = [geoFire queryAtLocation:center withRadius:0.6];

    // Query location by region
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center.coordinate, span);
    GFRegionQuery *regionQuery = [geoFire queryWithRegion:region];
```

**Swift:**

```
let center = CLLocation(latitude: 37.7832889, longitude: -122.4056973)
// Query locations at [37.7832889, -122.4056973] with a radius of 600 meters
var circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: 0.6)

// Query location by region
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001)
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center.coordinate, span)
var regionQuery = geoFire.queryWithRegion(region)
```

Comment: Well I thought so, however I might be missing something, but I can't see a way to access a list of objects that have been found within the specific region.

Comment: I can't test it right now but shouldn't there all the results in the circleQuery object?

Comment: There is no list, or anything like that, according to the docs: https://geofire-ios.firebaseapp.com/docs/Classes/GFCircleQuery.html
We can observe query completion, but the block attributes, are void, contrary to FEventTypeValue in Firebase